# Reading Device Manager's Property (Address ) Field of USb Webcam in Windows 7/10 using C#

Tags: c#, usb, device-manager

I have multiple Logitech Usb Webcam that are connected into the PC.

Now, I need to read the "Adress" field property of the Perticuler USB WebCam device.

I have googled and tried several System.Management codes BUt nothing helps.

Please advise me about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SetupAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791(v=vs.85).aspx).  You'll have to learn a lot of about the API and possibly add several PInvoke declarations to your program to use it if you cannot find a good C# wrapper for it that someone else has written.  The [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx), with its third argument set to `SPDRP_ADDRESS`, will probably do what you want.